# Python tail-like file read

Tags: python, io, fifo, with-statement

In test I redirected `stderr` into file and trying to read it in tail-like way.
So here is redirection:

```
class RedirectedEnv(object):
    def __init__(self, stderr=None):
        self._stderr = stderr or sys.stderr

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_stderr = sys.stderr
        self.old_stderr.flush()
        self.old_exit = getattr(sys, 'exit')
        sys.stderr = self._stderr

        def mock_exit():
            raise Exception
        sys.exit = mock_exit

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._stderr.flush()
        sys.stderr = self.old_stderr
        sys.exit = self.old_exit

        self._stderr.close()
```

and usage of it:

```
def test_invalid_args(self):
    with RedirectedEnv(stderr=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()):
        for args in [['-id', '123456789.00'], ['-i'], ['-i', '0'], ['-i', '../some_invalid_path/not_exist.json']]:
            try:
                self.parser.parse(args)
            except Exception:
                sys.stderr.flush()
                self.assertTrue(sys.stderr.readlines()[0].startswith("usage:")) <<-- here I need help
```

Is there some elegant way to do this? (Not making mess with `enumerate` and `tell()` with `seek()`) Maybe there some `FIFO queue` with file interface ?

Comment: Fix the indentation in the class definition

Comment: Why is `seek` messy? Shouldn't the `try` truncate the file on each loop and shouldn't the exception seek to the front of the file and read a line? Your test case is a little odd in that it catches all exceptions but doesn't seem to differentiate between when an option list should raise an exception and when it should not. Are some of these tests supposed to pass while others fail?

Comment: All should fail. I mocked sys.exit to prevent argparser from exiting interpreter, to check proper usage-message. Maybe it's not the best way) I opened file with "wb+", and it add content to the end, not rewritting it, so i can't just seek to the offset=0. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new file for each test and do a seek to the front to get its value. I moved to `TemporaryFile` since you don't use the file name.

```
def test_invalid_args(self):
    for args in [['-id', '123456789.00'], ['-i'], ['-i', '0'], ['-i', '../some_invalid_path/not_exist.json']]:
        with RedirectedEnv(stderr=tempfile.TemporaryFile()):
            try:
                self.parser.parse(args)
                raise AssertionError("should have failed")
            except Exception:
                sys.stderr.seek(0)
                self.assertTrue(sys.stderr.readline().startswith("usage:"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted. Compact and expressive, imho.